# Security Updates

Tags: windows, linux, macos, security

I have the triplet WIN/MAC/Ubuntu machines in my company.

I'm constantly getting security updates messages for all of them.

My questions are:

- how do Microsoft and the other companies find so many security holes?
- Sometimes I find out that I forgot to update a machine for a long time, how really vulnerable am I during this time?
- Don't hackers can just study the security updates on a daily basis and try to exploit 
  the machines that haven't updates yet?

Thanks

Comment: I think Niklas has pretty much answered your question, but you could also try posting it at ServerFault.com

Comment: No, don't repost. I've already flagged this to be moved to another SE site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how do Microsoft and the other companies find so many security holes?

Usually, they don't. From my experience, vendors themselves often don't put a lot of effort into actively finding and fixing their own vulnerabilities.

However, there are a lot of security researchers who try to find vulnerabilities using some combination of reverse engineering (static binary analysis and dynamic run-time analysis) and [fuzz testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzz_testing) to provoke misbehaviour, then evaluating the exploitability of the observed crashes.

The [Zero Day Initiative](http://www.zerodayinitiative.com/) is an example of a company that pays researchers and leaves vendors the time to fix found vulnerabilities before releasing details about them to the public (this process is called responsible disclosure).

> Sometimes I find out that I forgot to update a machine for a long
>   time, how really vulnerable am I during this time?

It depends on the type of vulnerability, but usually the answer is "Very, very much".

> Don't hackers can just study the security updates on a daily basis and
>   try to exploit the machines that haven't updates yet?

That's what they do. Often this is really easy, as proof-of-concept exploits for the patched vulnerabilities are publicly available. If this is not the case, it's at least possible to reverse-engineer the patches to get an idea of what the fixed vulnerability is. There's a [BitBlaze subproject](http://bitblaze.cs.berkeley.edu/apeg.html) that presents a proof-of-concept of how this process can be automated.